# Alternatives to "canvas.toDataURL("image/png");" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

I'm working on a Palm Pre app and I need to find an alternative to "canvas.toDataURL("image/png");". Ideally it could export the canvas image to a jpeg file but png would be find also.

Comment: Why would you want to export it to JPEG?

Comment: So people could save it to their phone and email / txt message it to others. I'm sure PNG would work fine though.

Answer (score 1):

The simple code available [here](http://nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/) might be helpful.

Comment: Sadly, WebOS does not support Canvas::getImageData() either.